# How does the Spring Boot Actuator work together with the Netflix Servo?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, metrics, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-servo

There are Spring Boot project that uses a Netflix Servo to collect metrics and send to Graphite.

I want to send metrics with the Spring Boot Actuator on Graphite, such as number request per every endpoint and time of response for every request, instead of creating custom metric.

But I ran into the problem. When I use the library only spring-boot-starter-actuator, then the desired parameters displays:
[image]

but when I apply library spring-cloud-starter-eureka, displayed only time of response from servo:
[image]

If someone faced with this problem, can you explain why it happens and how to solve it?

I use such version Spring Boot - 1.5.9.RELEASE and Spring Cloud - Edgware.SR1.

I will be glad to any response)

Link to test project: https://github.com/rmartseniuk/spring-metric